# Jenkins no connection to Applikation Server (Wildfly) on Openshift

Tags: jenkins, connection, openshift, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

i get som issues on doing a build via Jenkins on Openshift:

My config: Widfly8 + Jenkins (inclusive extra gear for build's)

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running AllgemeinTest.SimpleTest
Mar 27, 2014 11:59:59 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
Mar 27, 2014 11:59:59 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
Mar 27, 2014 11:59:59 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
Mar 27, 2014 12:00:09 PM org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer undeploy
WARN: Cannot undeploy: f10a9714-2d48-402e-980f-812475581a78.war
org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper$ServerDeploymentException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.11.7.1:9990. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.undeploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.undeploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.undeploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:152)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:205)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$4.call(ContainerDeployController.java:185)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.undeploy(ContainerDeployController.java:184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$2.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:119)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$2.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:110)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:249)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.undeployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.afterClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3$1.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.11.7.1:9990. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientServerDeploymentManager.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.AbstractServerDeploymentManager.execute(AbstractServerDeploymentManager.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.undeploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:106)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.11.7.1:9990. The connection timed out
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:204)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:148)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$1.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeAsync(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:101)
    ... 91 more

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 16.301 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  AllgemeinTest.SimpleTest: Cannot deploy: f10a9714-2d48-402e-980f-812475581a78.war

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:52.185s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 27 12:00:11 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/106M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) on project wildfly: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /var/lib/openshift/533449a4500446bed800003d/app-root/runtime/repo/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I do this from my Notebook against the Openshift Wildfly this is working great. And I got a BUILD SUCESS!

For me it seems to be, that the problem is for Jenkins to connect to the extra gear he starts for doing the build.

Here is my POM and my Arquillian.xml

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>wildfly</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <!-- Repositories, aus denen die benoetigte Software heruntergeladen werden 
        kann -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven 2 Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <name>java.net Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <name>Codehaus Maven 2 Repository</name>
            <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-weld</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>wildfly</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-web-common</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>Jenkins</system>
        <url>http://ci-myevent.rhcloud.com</url>
    </ciManagement>
</project>
```

Arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">


    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0">
        <property name="host">${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_IP}</property>
    </defaultProtocol>

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/arquillian</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="wildfly8" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementPort">${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_MANAGEMENT_HTTP_PORT}</property>
            <property name="username">${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_USERNAME}</property>
            <property name="managementAddress">${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_IP}</property>
            <property name="password">${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_PASSWORD}</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Has anybody an idea regarding this connections issue?

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: Have you enabled the native management interface for your wildfly? Once I got similar issues and noticed that by default the native management interface has been removed from the standard configuration for wildfly 8.0.0.Final.